# Spring Data - Redis repository doesn't sort with pageRequest

Tags: java, redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis

I am calling repository by id and pageRequest parameters but I cannot manage to sort the result. 
I call my repository in service layer as follow:

```
Sort sort = new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "dateTime");
PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest(0, 10, sort) ;
repository.findById(id, pageRequest);
```

And here is my repository class:

```
public interface QueryResultRepository extends CrudRepository<QueryResult, String>{
    Page<QueryResult> findById(String id, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Entity Class:

```
@RedisHash("queryresultdataredis")
public class QueryResultDataRedis {

    @Id
    private String id = null;
    @Indexed
    private String queryId = null;
    private String name;
```

[image]

Comment: It's all a bit weird since `findById` is supposed to return one entity by its primary ID (unique) or null. But please add your Entity class to see a bit clearer.

Comment: added it below the question. In fact the id is not unique

Comment: I noticed that Redis doesn't provide sorting functionality.